# Keras freezes while training several models iteratively

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I'm using Windows 10, Keras (release  2.3.1) and Tensorflow (release 2.1.0) with CUDA (release 10.1, V10.1.243) to train 20 residual network models on data from 20 subjects.

Unfortunately, the training randomly stops during the first epoch for model *k* (with k < 20). Sometimes k=3, sometimes k=7 and sometimes k=19. The only output I get is the following:

```
Train on 50634 samples, validate on 5626 samples
Epoch 1/200
```

The CPU workload constantly stays at 20 % (if I let it, even for days), while the GPU workload is stuck at 1 %. The task causing this workload is *Python* as I can tell from the task manager. I already tried to add the following code but without any success:

```
import tensorflow as tf
configproto = tf.compat.v1.ConfigProto() 
configproto.gpu_options.allow_growth = True
sess = tf.compat.v1.Session(config=configproto) 
tf.compat.v1.keras.backend.set_session(sess)
```

Any ideas are highly appreciated.

#### Update 1

Here is a snippet of my training loop:

```
    for testSubjectID in patientIDsForTesting:
        [testX,testY,trainX,trainY] = PrepareData.groupAndReturnDataAndBinaryAnnotationsForCurrentSubject()
        [scaledTrainX,scaledTestX] = PrepareData.scaleTrainingAndTestingData(trainX,testX)
        x_trainScaledWithoutValidationSet,x_validTrainScaled,y_trainWithoutValidationSet,y_validTrain = train_test_split(scaledTrainX,trainY,test_size=0.1,shuffle= True) 
        nb_classes = len(np.unique(np.concatenate((trainY,testY),axis =0)))
        y_true = np.array(testY, dtype=np.int64)

        y_trainWithoutValidationSetNumpyArray = np.array(y_trainWithoutValidationSet)
        testYNumpyArray = np.array(testY)
        y_validTrainNumpyArray = np.array(y_validTrain)
        trainXNumpyArray = np.array(trainX)

        enc = sklearn.preprocessing.OneHotEncoder()
        enc.fit(np.concatenate((y_trainWithoutValidationSetNumpyArray,testY),axis =0).reshape(-1,1))
        y_trainWithoutValidationSet = enc.transform(y_trainWithoutValidationSetNumpyArray.reshape(-1,1)).toarray()
        y_test = enc.transform(testYNumpyArray.reshape(-1,1)).toarray()
        y_valid = enc.transform(y_validTrainNumpyArray.reshape(-1,1)).toarray()

        scaledTestX = scaledTestX.reshape((scaledTestX.shape[0],scaledTestX.shape[1],1))
        x_validScaled = x_validTrainScaled.reshape((x_validTrainScaled.shape[0],x_validTrainScaled.shape[1],1))

        input_shape = x_trainScaledWithoutValidationSet.shape[1:] #x_trainScaled.shape[1:]
        Classifier = getResNetClassifier()
        Classifier.fit(x_trainScaledWithoutValidationSet,y_trainWithoutValidationSet,x_validScaled,y_valid,y_true)
```

Comment: It would be weird if you needed `tf1` configs to fix your  `tf2` issue, so I don't think that's it. Can you post your (preferably compacted) training loop (as in the loop that trains multiple models + the definition of the `tf.data.Dataset` / input_data)?

Comment: You are right about the t1 config. Didn't realize that mistake before. I also added a compact version of my training loop and hope that I didn't forget to include anything important.

Comment: you are not using `testSubjectId` anywhere in your loop, but it should still work though. Hmmm this one is hard. This could be a million things. I think your best bet is to just simply run every loop in a seperate process. It's pretty dirty, but at least then you know the garbage collection (because this is some sort of memory/GPU allocation issue) is supposed to work: `subprocess.call('python3 loop_body.py --testSubjectd {}'.format(testSubjectId) `something like thath.

Comment: "testSubjectId" is not used because I condensed the code artificially. In reality, it is used. I will give your approach a try. Thanks a lot.